# How to keep together all the information of a record on a single page of report using CPP REPORT MAX?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I am developing a report application which is used to generate reports. I have a database from which the data is coming into the report. Currently my report is displaying data of a record being split over multiple pages like being show in the screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Look at my MS ACCESS database. As you can see that every record has multiple subjects associated with it. And i want to display them (each 6 of a record) one per page. How can i group them on a page using CPP REPORT MAX tool?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cppmax.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=54&PID=150&title=how-to-get-multiple-rows-on-one-page-of-a-report#150

You should be adding the Page Break as the last control on the page. Remove it, then add it after you add all your other controls in the Detail section.